# How to retrieve and save HTML viewer's information in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web, google-analytics

I have a HTML homepage publicly available. Using Google Analytics, it provides some viewer's demographic information, also the OS, browser, etc.

I want to get as much information as possible from the viewer, especially OS login name or username, and save them in a `.txt` file. How can I do that in javascript (or any possible means embedded in my HTML)?

For instance, in Java, one would do `System.getProperty("user.name");` to get user's name.

Comment: Based on the give answer, I am able to get only the browser info but not the logged in User Info. are you able to get the solution. If so, Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

by your

> any possible means embedded in my HTML

i assume you are open to any technology including php?

well php has a built in function for this:
look up [php documtation for user os and browser agent info](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php/%22php%20documentation%20for%20that%22)

you could also try this in php:

```
<?php $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ?>
```

it will return something like:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; IEMB3)
```

you could also use  [Google code Browscap class](http://code.google.com/p/phpbrowscap/)
and its gonna be a matter of few lines to get a lotta users info

this is another ready made php solution at [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/545047/Get-Browser-and-Operating-System-with-PHP) all you will have to do is copy the class; instantiate it and then do this;

```
 echo $obj->showInfo('browser');

    // get browser version
  echo $obj->showInfo('version');

  // get Operating system
  echo $obj->showInfo('os');
```

> to write the data to text file maybe only browser info using the class will be;

```
  <?php
   $file = 'file.txt';
      $data = $obj->showInfo('browser');
  file_put_contents($file, $data);
   ?>
```

dont want to use php?

try this makeshift javascript solution to get user's os info

```
var OSName ="a name to give the os if it doesnt match the listed";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";
```

this should return an OS name like: windows or MacOS

```
document.write('Your OS: '+OSName);
```

alternatively try this solution too:

```
<div id="demo"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

        UserInfoString = "<span>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</span>";
        UserInfoString+= "<span>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</span>";
        UserInfoString+= "<span>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</span>";
        UserInfoString+= "<span>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</span>";
        UserInfoString+= "<span>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</span>";
        UserInfoString+= "<span>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</span>";

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=UserInfoString;

       </script>
```

Comment: I'm more interested in getting user-specific info, such as Computer name or username. Any means to do that?

Comment: when you say `Computer name or username` what exactly do you mean? like 'hp pavilion', 'del inpirion' kinda name? be specific

Comment: Username is clear: User's login name, as in my example for Java. Computer name is computer's name which is set by the user at the time of OS installation. In windows FYI: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/pictures/computer-name.jpg

Comment: BTW, the real IP value is also not there in Google Analytics. Retrieving that is also good.